# Dynatree "got invalid load event"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Im working on a project related to nested folder structure, This folder structure was implemented through dynatree concept. We store the visited folder id (unique id) to map the tree node. When we refresh the page we used to invoke the previously visited folder by using the stored folder id. Everything seems to work but sometimes the folders failed to expand rather it stops at the root itself. this seems to be strange because it is happening only sometimes. When debugged we found that an exception is being thrown and is successfully caught, but it does not result in expanding the folder.

The exception is **got invalid load event**

But the eventType variable seems to be fine, with correct string,
Im new to dynatree, can someone help me on this

```
 var eventType = "nodeLoaded.dynatree." + node.tree.$tree.attr("id") + "." + node.data.key;
 try {
     node.tree.$tree.trigger(eventType, [node, true]); // exception thrown
 } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);  //this is the place where exception is logged
 }
```

Comment: I fixed this issue. The reason is that there were many asynchronous ajax calls that will load the tree to its last node, these asynchronous calls might sometime overlap while node of the tree is expanding. Thats why the exception was thrown for me. I fixed this issue by making the calls to be synchronous. Now the ajax call will be thrown one after the other

Answer (score -1):

Dynatree is no longer maintained, you could consider to switch to Fancytree. It supports an ‚ext-persist‘ extension to restore the tree state after reload.

Comment: This should be a comment.